# Javascript how to efficiently filter and access an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have an array in this format

```
    var data = [
                 "Author Name: Employee1"
               ],
               [
                 "Earnings",
                 "Amount",
                 "Deductions",
                 "Amount",
                 "Take Home"
               ],
               [
                 "Regular",
                 "2,500.00",
                 "Coop Loan",
                 "1,500.00"
               ],
                [
                 "Author Name: Employee2"
               ],
               [
                 "Earnings",
                 "Amount",
                 "Deductions",
                 "Amount",
                 "Take Home"
               ],
               [
                 "Regular",
                 "3,500.00",
                 "Coop Loan",
                 "1,500.00"
               ],
```

I'm trying to get the value next to `Regular` `Array` which is the Amounts ["2,500","3,500"]

What I did first was to filter the array,

```
$.each(data, function(a,b){ // loop 1
    earnings_list = b.filter(function(z){ 
        if(/^Regular/.test(z) == true) 
        {
            $.each(data, function(x,y){ // loop 2
                 if(x == a) // compare if keys matches
                 {
                   console.log("key: "+a+"  amount: "+y[1]);
                 }
            });
         }
     });  
});
```

output is

```
key: 2 amount: 2,500
key: 5 amount: 3,500
```

In this loop I was able to get the regular `amount ["2,500"",3,500"]`
however, I'm repeating myself,I have two loops with the same data just to compare it's keys,

I have hundreds to a thousand of fields and records to filter that could slowdown the processing, I have to do a rework on this,

I hope someone can give me advise how to optimize my code without repeating my loop, thank you,!

Comment: You have an array of arrays, not arrays of objects.

Comment: There are some serious issues with this question regarding the structure of your example code and the actual text of what you are asking. Anyway, just use `indexOf(stringName) > -1` instead of `== stringName`.... that is, once you figure out how to get this into an array of objects and not an array of arrays.

Comment: Invalid syntax half way. Please provide your code and *valid* input and desired output.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Perhaps a regular expression like `/^Author Name/.test(value)` which will return true if *value* starts with the characters "Author Name:".

Comment: my expected output is an array displaying `Author Name: User` and `Author Name: User2`

Answer (score 1):

*From comments*

> my expected output is an array displaying Author Name: User and Author
>   Name: User2

You can use `reduce` (to get a flattened array) and `filter`

```
var search = "Author Name";
var output = arr.reduce( ( a, c ) => a.concat(c), [] ).filter( s => s && s.indexOf( search ) != -1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [
  [
    "Requirements List"
  ],
  [
    "System Name: TEST"
  ],
  [
    "Program/Module Name: TESTs"
  ],
  [
    "Author Name: USER",
    null,
    "Sap Number: 7774"
  ],
  [
    "Earnings",
    "Amount",
    "Deductions",
    "Amount",
    "Take Home"
  ],
  [
    "Regular",
    "2,500.00",
    "Coop Loan",
    "1,500.00"
  ],
  [
    "Overtime",
    "1,500.00",
    "Tax",
    "2,200.00"
  ],
  [
    "Holidays",
    "700.00",
    "Gym",
    "0.00"
  ],
  [
    "Bonus",
    "1,000.00"
  ],
  [
    "Birthday",
    "0.00"
  ],
  [
    "Total Earnings",
    "5,700.00",
    "Total Deduction",
    "3,700.00",
    "2,000.00"
  ],
  [
    "System Name: ETEASDASr"
  ],
  [
    "Program/Module Name: EAASDA"
  ],
  [
    "Author Name: USER2",
    null,
    "Sap Number: 7774"
  ],
  [
    "Earnings",
    "Amount",
    "Deductions",
    "Amount",
    "Take Home"
  ],
  [
    "Regular",
    "3,500.00",
    "Coop Loan",
    "1,500.00"
  ],
  [
    "Overtime",
    "1,500.00",
    "Tax",
    "2,200.00"
  ],
  [
    "Holidays",
    "700.00",
    "Gym",
    "0.00"
  ],
  [
    "Bonus",
    "1,000.00"
  ],
  [
    "Birthday",
    "0.00"
  ],
  [
    "Total Earnings",
    "6,700.00",
    "Total Deduction",
    "3,700.00",
    "3,000.00"
  ],

];
var search = "Author Name";
var output = arr.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), []).filter(s => s && s.indexOf(search) != -1);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @RobG I'll have to loop `c` inside the `reduce` callback anyways. It will get a little more messier and difficult to read. This current approach looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to get just the values you want, I've reduced the sample data. Storing the regular expression as a variable might help performance a tad:

```js
var data = [
  [
    "Requirements List"
  ],
  [
    "Author Name: USER",
    null,
    "Sap Number: 7774"
  ],
  [
    "Regular",
    "3,500.00",
    "Coop Loan",
    "1,500.00"
  ],
  [
    "Author Name: USER2",
    null,
    "Sap Number: 7774"
  ]
]

// Loop over contents of data
var authors = data.reduce(function(acc, arr) {
  // Get elements starting with "Author Name" and append to accumulator
  return acc.concat(arr.filter(function(s){return /^Author Name:/.test(s)}));
}, []);

console.log(authors);

// Using arrow functions:
var authors2 = data.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr.filter(s => /^Author Name:/.test(s))), []);

console.log(authors2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by checking the item and if it is an array, then call then take the callback for the array. If not, check the value and concat it to the result set, if included.

```js
var data = [["Requirements List"], ["System Name: TEST"], ["Program/Module Name: TESTs"], ["Author Name: USER", null, "Sap Number: 7774"], ["Earnings", "Amount", "Deductions", "Amount", "Take Home"], ["Regular", "2,500.00", "Coop Loan", "1,500.00"], ["Overtime", "1,500.00", "Tax", "2,200.00"], ["Holidays", "700.00", "Gym", "0.00"], ["Bonus", "1,000.00"], ["Birthday", "0.00"], ["Total Earnings", "5,700.00", "Total Deduction", "3,700.00", "2,000.00"], ["System Name: ETEASDASr"], ["Program/Module Name: EAASDA"], ["Author Name: USER2", null, "Sap Number: 7774"], ["Earnings", "Amount", "Deductions", "Amount", "Take Home"], ["Regular", "3,500.00", "Coop Loan", "1,500.00"], ["Overtime", "1,500.00", "Tax", "2,200.00"], ["Holidays", "700.00", "Gym", "0.00"], ["Bonus", "1,000.00"], ["Birthday", "0.00"], ["Total Earnings", "6,700.00", "Total Deduction", "3,700.00", "3,000.00"]],
    search = 'Author Name',
    result = data.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        return Array.isArray(a)
            ? a.reduce(iter, r)
            : r.concat(('' + a).includes(search) ? a : []);
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```